# "Sound of sorting"

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

I was writing a small program in python 2.7.10 with pygame. Im using multithreading to play sounds (with winsound) and still draw things fast. I was trying to replicate a similar idea of some videos i saw on youtube of sorting algorithms. Unfortunately it runs for about 10 seconds then randomly crashes, the sounds keep going but the pygame window goes not responding and the drawing does not change. Even if i put a print "hi" in the code somewhere it will still be printing in the console but pygame will still have gone not responding. Cant think of whats wrong but it may be something with the multithreading (im very new to it!)

```
from random import randint
import pygame,winsound,threading,time
from pygame.locals import *
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([1000,500])
def bubbleSort(listName):
    sorting=True
    while sorting:

        listChanged=False
        for i in range(len(listName)-1):
            draw(listName,1000/len(listName),500/11,i)

            if listName[i] < listName[i+1]:
                listName[i],listName[i+1]=listName[i+1],listName[i]
                threading.Thread(target=playsound,args=([listName[i]])).start()
                listChanged=True
        if not listChanged:
            sorting=False
            time.sleep(10)
            pygame.quit()

def playsound(frequency):
    winsound.Beep(frequency*100,100)




def draw(listName,width,height,comparing):
    print "hi"
    screen.fill([0,0,0])
    for i in range(len(listName)):
        if i == comparing or i == comparing+1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,[0,255,0],[width*(len(listName)-i),500-(height*listName[i]),width,500])
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,[255,255,255],[width*(len(listName)-i),500-(height*listName[i]),width,500])
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    pygame.display.update()  




list1=[]
for i in range(100):
    list1.append(randint(1,10))

threading.Thread(target=bubbleSort,args=([list1])).start()
```

Comment: FYI my code can be very confusing for people that are not me

Comment: Do all of the drawing from the same thread. Create the output window in the same thread as where it draws. Mixing draw calls across threads is likely to be problematic.

Comment: What causes it to wait for anything to finish?

Comment: i tried that but still crashes, its very strange!

Comment: Well winsound seems to pause everything while its playing a sound for the length you want it to play

Comment: New paste, fixed what you said but it still happens.

Comment: When you say "the sound keeps going" do you mean it just plays about a half second of the same thing repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, heres the new paste .http://pastebin.com/t0Y7EU4S

Comment: That is what happens when a program crashes while playing sound. The OS tries to notify the program to update the sound buffer, but it crashed, so it doesn't update it, and the hardware keeps playing whatever is still there in the buffer. The sound probably isn't the problem. You need to wait for that thread to finish before you let the main function return.

Comment: Well i can do that with putting winsound in the main function but it slows it down MASSIVLY. The code waits for the sound to finish playing then continues. With mine it waits 100 miliseconds. Under 100 miliseconds it sounds wierd

Comment: That has nothing to do with the thread.

Comment: But if i put the winsound beep in the main function it sleeps, but if i multithread it they run together so im confused on how to make it run fast and play the sound

Comment: Where you create the thread, store it in a variable, then `.start()` it, then `.join()` it. If you do that, the thread provides no benefit, but it should fix the crash. Starting the thread at the end is nonsense because there's nothing to do for the main thread.

Comment: Describe how it is not identical to just calling bubbleSort on the main thread.

Comment: Ok now i have no clue. I removed the threading of the sound function and just put it into the main function. So the sorting is SLOOOWW but it still crashes. I have no clue. Have you ran the code on your machine?

Comment: I can't, I use Linux. `winsound` sounds like it is windows-only.

Comment: Ok so the difference is that if i use threading the drawing does not wait for the sound to finish playing so it can sort faster. If i put it in the main loop it has to wait for the sound to finish playing then draw it again

Comment: At the *end* when there is *nothing left to do* it creates the thread. Then what? Then nothing. Then it just runs one thing again, just in another thread. And nothing stops the main thread from exiting before the sort finishes.

Comment: I dunno but im sure it waits for the sound to finish when its in the main function but when i multithread it, it seems to run faster

Comment: Ok, I'm done trying to convince you. Good luck.

Comment: Like when its in the main loop i can feel a delay between drawing but multithreading its drawing it instantly

Comment: Hahaa, np thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Fixed it anyway, i just dont thread the main function and it seems to work, dont ask me why!

Comment: I guess I can repeat myself one more time: nothing prevents the main thread from exiting while the thread is running. It starts shutting everything down and crashes the thread.